# How to align divs like in chat?

Tags: html, css

How to align divs like in chat , incoming messages on the left side, outcoming on the right. Check image below

[image]

Comment: Please show us some snipet with CSS & HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `flexbox` solution to get your started. `speaker1` begins from the start of the row and `speaker2` is pinned to the end of the row. Each row is 75% the width of the parent container. You can adjust that width as necessary.

```css
.chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.chat>* {
  width: 75%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1em;
}

.speaker1 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.speaker2 {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="chat">
  <li class="speaker1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit pariatur voluptatibus unde illo animi soluta odit minus fugiat. Veniam numquam quam illum praesentium quibusdam impedit, voluptate ratione nesciunt dolores dolorem!</li>
  <li class="speaker2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
  <li class="speaker2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint excepturi praesentium illum, hic alias, totam porro ipsum esse magni eaque! Labore ullam dolorem quia. Porro autem, corrupti aliquid eligendi repellendus.</li>
  <li class="speaker1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam ipsum neque molestias eius, obcaecati ab optio nesciunt quibusdam amet est accusantium, sit, libero dolores. Tenetur quibusdam cumque, vitae nisi veniam!</li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwd9s1om/5/)